# Testing Server Error Handling in Play application

Tags: scala, error-handling, playframework

I have a proxy Play application server (server A) in front of another server (server B). When a server error happens on this proxy server A, I would like to make a request to the other server B and return its response, and if that fails too, return with an Internal Server Error.

From what I understand, you can catch errors on a dev env and prod env but not on a test env (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaErrorHandling#Extending-the-default-error-handler)

```
/**
   * Invoked in dev mode when a server error occurs.
   *
   * @param request The request that triggered the error.
   * @param exception The exception.
   */
  protected def onDevServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: UsefulException): Future[Result] =
    Future.successful(InternalServerError(views.html.defaultpages.devError(playEditor, exception)))

/**
   * Invoked in prod mode when a server error occurs.
   *
   * Override this rather than [[onServerError]] if you don't want to change Play's debug output when logging errors
   * in dev mode.
   *
   * @param request The request that triggered the error.
   * @param exception The exception.
   */
  protected def onProdServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: UsefulException): Future[Result] =
    Future.successful(InternalServerError(views.html.defaultpages.error(exception)))
```

I would like to know if I would be able to test the above scenario (return response of server B when server A fails) in the test env.